# Uploading a file with other variables in Actionscript 3 using URLLoader?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, upload

I'm trying to upload a file through URLLoader in Actionscript 3, I know it's possible, at least according to the docs, but I can't figure it. So if anyone has done this before I'd love to know what I'm leaving out, specifically, I'm unsure about URLRequest and its data property. I know that my file's data should go there, but I'm unsure as to how.

Here's a very rudimentary form of the code I'm working with:

```
//===============================================
public function sendRequest():void {
//===============================================

  var newFile:FileReference(); //this eventually gets data loaded to it before I make request
  var sendForm:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  var urlString:String = "/proposal_request/?";
  var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Disposition: attache[attachment]; filename=" + newFile.name);
  ...

  ...
  urlString += "variable=" + instance_name.text;
  urlString += "another_variable=" + another_instance_name.text;
  ...

  ...
  var requester:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
  requester.contentType = "multipart/form-data";
  requester.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  requester.requestHeaders.push(header);
  requester.data = newFile; //here's where I'm most confused, should this be encoded?
  ...

  ...
  sendForm.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, responseStatus);
  sendForm.load(requester);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always go that way -- but you really don't have to.

The *FileReference* class provide you an easy way to upload a file: the method [*upload()*](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html#upload()).

```
public function upload(request:URLRequest, uploadDataFieldName:String = "Filedata", testUpload:Boolean = false):void
```

After your *FileReference object* has some data, simply call *upload* passing an *URLRequest* and optionally a datafield string, with some extra information for the server, and a boolean that will (de)activate the test upload: if your file is over 10KB, the flash player will try to send a 0 byte file as a connection test before uploading the real file.

After that you can just listen for *progress*, *complete* and *uploadDataComplete* events to keep track of the upload.

[*Adobe AS3 Reference on FileReference.upload()*](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html#upload())

Comment: Man I've been on that page a bunch and I never thought you could pass a URLRequest to upload, don't know why, it only makes sense. I guess I was just checking too much stuff out. Thanks Kishi.

Answer (score 0):

The above is fine if you are not changing file data after browse using FileReference. Suppose you resize the image or crop the image before upload, how will you upload using FileReference.upload.

URLLoader can be used to send binary data to server but in this case upload progress is not available as ProgressEvent is fired only after the image has been completely uploaded.

Is there a way to show intermediate image upload progress for the resized images, similar to the one by displayed by FileReference component.

Comment: Nice question inside an answer to a question, dude